# Get the whole ROW which has the MAX value of the column SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

[image: Sample]

I want to do the above in SQL Server 2008. Any ideas?

Comment: how do you want to handle months where the max value is shared by two days?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/sql-fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

Setup:

```
declare @MyTable table(Year int, Month int, Day int, Total int)

insert @MyTable
values
    (2005, 9, 23, 12),
    (2005, 9, 26, 5),
    (2005, 9, 24, 1),
    (2005, 9, 15, 28),
    (2005, 9, 21, 1),
    (2005, 9, 13, 1),
    (2005, 10, 31, 5),
    (2005, 11, 18, 115),
    (2005, 11, 20, 1),
    (2005, 11, 11, 1),
    (2005, 11, 19, 1)
```

Query:

```
;with cte
as
(
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by Year, Month order by Total desc) RowNumber
    from @MyTable
)
select Year, Month, Day, Total 
from cte
where RowNumber = 1
```

Output:

```
Year        Month       Day         Total
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2005        9           15          28
2005        10          31          5
2005        11          18          115
```